# JavaScript convert long decimal to hex and back

Tags: javascript, hex, converters

#### Prolog

I been experiencing something funny with JavaScript and I can't find why.
I'm pretty sure its me and not the JavaScript.

#### Problem

When converting the integer number `72058145430680163` (18 digits) **to hex**, I obtain the hexadecimal representation `10000806191b260`.

Although using the [Dec2Hex converter RapidTables](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-hex.html) I get `10000806191b263`. Latter is the correct number - 3 more then my result using Javascript.

Moreover, when converting my result **back to int**, it does return `72058145430680160` - 3 less then my original source integer.

#### Javascript used for conversion

Convert from dec to hex:

```
(72058145430680163).toString(16);
```

Convert from hex to dec (backwards):

```
parseInt((72058145430680163).toString(16), 16)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're beyond the maximum integer precision. Try `console.log(72058145430680163)` -> 72058145430680160 even without any conversions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are beyond the limits of JavaScript maximum.  Use BigInt instead.

```
BigInt("72058145430680163").toString('16'); // Returns 10000806191b263 as String
```

And this does the whole round trip

```
BigInt("0x" + BigInt("72058145430680163").toString('16')).toString() // Retuns 72058145430680163
```

More information on BigInt here:
    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Answer (score 2):

Your number is too large for Javascript. So what you're seeing occur is some overflow issues. What you can do to circumvent this is utilize the Javascript data-type *BigInt*.

So in practice, you could do something like this:

```js
BigInt("72058145430680163").toString(16);
```